# swift 3, ios 10 - push notification firebase is not received

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) and [this project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios%20as%20references) as my references. This is my code in AppDelegate

```
import UIKit 
import UserNotifications 
import Firebase 

@UIApplicationMain 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { 

     var window: UIWindow? 
     let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id" 
     let preferences = UserDefaults.standard 

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { 

         Messaging.messaging().delegate = self 

         if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { 
             UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self 

             let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound] 
             UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization( 
                 options: authOptions, 
                 completionHandler: {_, _ in }) 
         } else { 
             let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = 
                 UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil) 
             application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings) 
         } 

         application.registerForRemoteNotifications() 
         FirebaseApp.configure() 
         return true 
     } 

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) { 
         if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] { 
             print("Message ID: \(messageID)") 
         } 

         print("message1:",userInfo) 

     } 

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], 
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) { 
         if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] { 
             print("Message ID: \(messageID)") 
         } 

         print("message2:", userInfo) 

         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData) 

     } 

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

         print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)") 
     } 

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) { 

         print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)") 
         let apn = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined() 

     } 

     func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) { 

         Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo) 

     } 
} 

@available(iOS 10, *) 
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

     func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification, 
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) { 
         let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo 

         if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] { 
             print("Message ID: \(messageID)") 
         } 

         print("userinfo", userInfo) 

         completionHandler([]) 
     } 

     func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { 
         let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo 

         if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] { 
             print("Message ID: \(messageID)") 
         } 

         print("userinfo", userInfo) 

         completionHandler() 
     } 
 } 


extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate { 

     func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) { 

         print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)") 

     } 

     func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) { 
         print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)") 

     } 
 }
```

I got fcmtoken and APNs token. I've uploaded my Development APNs certificate. I've turned Push Notification on Capabilities to ON. I've tried it on my device. I've added GoogleService-Info.plist on my project. But I haven't received any notification from either the foreground or the background.

Did I make any mistake on my code? Or should I need to update my certificate? I am pretty new to this by the way.

Can anyone help me to solve it? I really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because I haven't uploaded the Production APNs Certificate, guys. I thought I don't need it because I saw on [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/) and it used just Development APNs certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your `deviceTokenString` or `deviceTokenId` in the database, and you have to have correct distribution or development certificate according to your need, this things are the basic need for to receive push-notification.

From your code, you didn't register `deviceTokenString/Id`.

Thanks

Comment: i've added code to add deviceTokenString to database but still no notification appear. I also have correct development certificate too. I have no idea of this. Thanks for your response by the way :)